# If $A \subset \mathcal{N}^2$ is a $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$ set, then $\{x : (x,x) \in A\}$ is also $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$.

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

This is the boldface Borel hierarchy on Baire space.

Jech states this with a "clearly". What am I missing that makes the statement completely obvious?

I clearly have zero intuition for this material.

Comment: Oh, yes. I was far too hasty in my induction... Jech makes the statement for $U$ a universal $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$ set for any $\alpha \geq 1$, and says it's obvious. (a) Why is it obvious? (b) Is it true for $\alpha > 1$ for arbitrary $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$ sets, and if so, why is this obvious? I clearly have no intuition for this material.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Isn't the base case $\alpha=1$ also OK, provided $\{x:(x,x)\in A\}$ is understood as a subset of $\mathcal N$. Somewhere,an induction on $\alpha$ will be needed, though it might be considered "obvious". But maybe that induction was done in a theorem saying that levels of the Borel hierarchy are preserved by inverse images under continuous functions. Then all you need here is to observe that the function $\mathcal N\to\mathcal N^2:x\mapsto(x,x)$ is continuous.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Quite right, I misread the question and thought it was working in $\mathcal{N}^2$ all the way through.

Comment: Ah yes. And the inverse image part is indeed, to me, obvious. Thank you for answering my extremely silly question. Like I said, I have zero intuition yet for how to go about thinking about this, but hopefully I will develop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Show by induction on $\alpha$ that the preimage of a $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ set under a continuous function is again $\Sigma^0_\alpha$. This uses continuity trivially for the base case, and for the induction step the fact that preimage commutes with $\cap $ and $\cup$; note that this is *false* for image!

---

Note that by contrast, $\{(x, x): (x, x)\in A\}$ is *not* $\Sigma^0_1$ necessarily even if $A$ is; but this does work for $\alpha>1$. The key point is that for $\beta<\alpha$, $\Pi^0_\beta\subseteq \Sigma^0_\alpha$, and each pointclass $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ is closed under finite intersections.

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed obvious. I just did not consider thinking about it with inverse images.